# rollup not detecting @import syntax for scss files

Tags: javascript, reactjs, sass, rollup, rollupjs

i need rollup to bundle my sass files, like variables, mixins etc.
index.scss contains

```
@import "./scss/variables.scss";
```

and index.ts contains

```
import "./index.scss";
export { Button } from "./components/Button";
```

however the bundle does NOT have any code from variables.scss, and if i use a variable inside of say Button.scss i get this error

```
[!] (plugin postcss) Error: Undefined variable: "$shady-lady".
```

my rollup config

```
export default {
  input: "./src/index.ts",
  output: [
    {
      file: packageJson.main,
      format: "cjs",
      sourcemap: true,
    },
    {
      file: packageJson.module,
      format: "esm",
      sourcemap: true,
    },
  ],
  plugins: [
    resolve(),
    cleaner({
      targets: ["./lib"],
    }),
    postcss({
      extract: true,
      modules: true,
      minimize: true,
      plugins: [postcssImport(), autoprefixer()],
      extensions: [".scss"],
    }),
    peerDepsExternal(),
    commonjs(),
    typescript({
      exclude: ["**/*.stories.tsx", "**/*.test.tsx"],
    }),
  ],
};
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

so the problem wasn't with the @import syntax. it was rollup not handling global resources files.

the solution was to remove the import './index.scss' from index.ts and just use this package

https://github.com/hytromo/rollup-plugin-postcss-retain-sass-data#readme